# Does the Perl cons build tool skip targets containing dotnames?

Tags: perl

I want to create a directory in the target area with one file.  I'm observing that if any
of the segments in the target path starts with a `"."`, cons quietly fails to create the
target.

Anyone know how I can get around this?  The mailing list looks dead -- the last email in
the mailman archive was sent in **2008/10** .  I've sent an email to the current maintainer,
but given how moribund the site looks, I'm not sure he's still around.

Unfortunately, switching to Rake currently isn't an option.  I'm trying to hit a
deadline tonight.

Comment: Did you try dev version of cons, 2.3.0?

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging messages in Cons?  add `-d` to the commandline.